# How to bind dynamic data to angular-tree-grid?

Tags: angular, typescript

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

How to bind dynamic data. I am using **angular-tree-grid** but i am not able to bind dynamic data.

```
<html>    
    <db-angular-tree-grid 
        (expand)="onExpand($event)"
        [data]="data" 
        [configs]="configs">
    </db-angular-tree-grid> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain which code piece is throwing the error? And make sure **data** is initialized properly.

Comment: Can you show  piece of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your variable `data` isn't set initially, and angular-tree-grid tries to `.map()` something.

Need to see more of your code, but try this:

```html
<db-angular-tree-grid
    *ngIf="data"
    (expand)="onExpand($event)"
    [data]="data" 
    [configs]="configs">
</db-angular-tree-grid>
```

OR setting a default value as an empty array:

```html
<db-angular-tree-grid
    (expand)="onExpand($event)"
    [data]="data || []" 
    [configs]="configs">
</db-angular-tree-grid>
```

Comment: this works for me                                                                                                       
    <db-angular-tree-grid
    (expand)="onExpand($event)"
    [data]="data || []" 
    [configs]="configs">
</db-angular-tree-grid>